# Get all files inside directory's in jar file in java

Tags: java

Lets say the location of my project is "some/random/guy", and inside the project there is a directory located with the path "some/random/guy/versions", I want to get all files/directory's inside that folder so I can get all the availible versions.
But the versions dir only gets created once the project is compiled, so its not in my IDE.

After searching like 2 hours already I couldn't find my answer.

Currently Im using the code from oracle docs but it also doesn't work:

```
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("some/random/guy/versions"))) {
        for (Path file: stream) {
            System.out.println(file.getFileName());
        }
    } catch (IOException | DirectoryIteratorException e) {
        System.err.print(e);
    }
```

How can I get all files/directory's inside any folder thats located inside a jar file?

I would like to avoid unzipping the jar file if possible, thanks.

Comment: Where is the jar you mention? Is the path "some/random/guy/versions" inside a jar or a folder that contains jars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will show contents of any jar/zip archive using NIO FileSystem handling, you need to pass in a location of the jar and optional path under the jar:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path jar = Path.of(args[0]);
    String relPath = args.length > 1 ? args[1] : "/";

    System.out.println("ZIP/JAR: "+jar+" isRegularFile()="+Files.isRegularFile(jar));

    try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(jar)) {
        Path path = fs.getPath(relPath);
        System.out.println("SCAN "+ jar+" starting at path: "+path);

        try(Stream<Path> str = Files.find(path, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (p,a) -> true)) {
            str.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it altough I had to change some code but this did the job!

Answer (score 0):

`jar` file is plain old `zip` archive. You do not neet unzip `jar` to get all entries' names, because `zip` files contains `CentralDirectory`. All you need is to use standard `ZipInputStream` or one of framework, e.g. [zip4jvm](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/zip4jvm):

```
import ru.olegcherednik.zip4jvm.ZipMisc;

public static List<String> getAllEntryNames(Path jar) throws IOException {
    return ZipMisc.zip(jar).getEntries()
                  .map(ZipFile.Entry::getFileName)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This snippet retrieves all existed entry names. Directory (if they exists as separate entry) ends with `/`.